# QWebFrame print in a separate thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, printing, qwebpage

In my qt application I'm printing some large html code from a QWebFrame (mainFrame from a QWebPage). The html code contains some inline images and takes a while to be printed. Therefore I tried to put the print call into a separate thread to keep the gui responsive. As mentioned in the docs I thought this should be possible [(Painting in threads)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#painting-in-threads).

But I still get the famous "QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread"

My code to print is as follows:

```
void PrintDialog::paintRequested(QPrinter *printer) {
  futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>();
  QEventLoop q;
  connect(futureWatcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &q, SLOT(quit()), Qt::UniqueConnection);
  futureWatcher->setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(m_webPage->mainFrame(), &QWebFrame::print, printer));
  q.exec();
}
```

To clarify all objects reside in the gui thread and the html gets generated before. The images get inlined like follows:

```
QImage image
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG");

QString html = "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + QString(ba.toBase64() + "\"/>";
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Is it that the QWebFrame internally uses some QPixmaps? Is there any solution for using the QWebFrame::print call in another thread?